# Reducing time complexity from n^2

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There are `n` students in a class. Soon, there's going to be an inter-school science quiz, where there'll be questions on 4 subjects, call them 1,2,3 and 4 for simplicity. There should 2 students in a team. Any student is equally likely to be good or bad at a particular subject.

We are given as input n rows, each with 4 entries in it. The student is good at `i`-th subject if the `i`-th column is equal to 1. I'm supposed to find out the total number of ways in which the school can send a team so that the two students together know all the 4 subjects.

For example,

```
S1: 1 1 1 1
S2: 1 1 0 1
S3: 1 0 1 1
S4: 0 0 1 1
S5: 0 0 0 0
```

Student 1 can go with any student since all the subjects are his strength. => 4

Student 2 can go with S3 and S4, since S2 is good in subject 1,2 and 4 and S3 and S4 are good in subject 3. => 2 (Note that (S1,S2) was already counted)

S3 will go with the one good at subject 2=> none

S4: Similarly, none.

Hence, ans=4+2=6

My solution:-

```
ans=0;
//arr is the array containing subject-wise "strength" of students
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    ArrayList<Integer> a=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        if(arr[i][j]==0)
            a.add(j);
    if(a.size()==0)
        ans+=n-i-1;
    else
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            bool=false;
            for(int k=0;k<a.size();k++){
                if(arr[j][a.get(k)]==0)
                    break;
                bool=true;
            }
            if(bool)
                ans++;
        }
}
System.out.println(ans);
```

Now I know my solution is correct, but its time complexity is O(n^2), and I'm looking for a better solution for the same. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the entire problem statement from where you got this question? Not very clear to me.

Comment: @vivek_23 leave the statement. I'll just tell you what we actually have to do. There's a n*4 array. We have to find the number of unordered pairs of rows such that the entries arr[][i], i=0,1,2,3 are 1 for at least one of those two. I hope its better...

Comment: Please supply an example or two.  The final sentence is unclear.  Does each team have to cover all 4 subjects?  Do we need to find every such team (with some students appearing on more than one team), or is this a full roster (disjoint teams)?

Comment: @user11067275 what if a single student knew everything?

Comment: @Prune yes each team has to cover 4 subjects. Yes a student can appear on multiple teams. Also, I've put some examples

Comment: @vivek_23 please check the example. S1 knew everything, so he's cool with any of the other 4 guys

Comment: Hint: You can look at it as decimal numbers ranging from 0-15.

Comment: @vivek -- that doesn't work; S2 needs someone with a `1` in the 2's spot.  Someone with a value of 4, for instance, would not form a viable team.

Comment: @vivek_23 I thought that way too, but it won't work. For example, if someone had `0 1 0 1`, it's 5 (more than 2), but its not good with `S2`

Comment: @NicoSchertler: that conclusion doesn't follow.  There are problems for which you can compute the quantity of solutions without delineating those solutions.

Comment: @Prune Fair enough. In that case, we can just loop from 0 to 15 to see who all will have that bit set in the 2's spot. Here, we will have an array of 0 to 15 where we can have a count of how many times it occurred, adding them to the final answer.

Comment: @vivek_23 If I understand you correctly, that's what I'm doing, my arraylist `a` contains the indices/subjects that are 0 for a particular student and then I loop it over the remaining students...

Comment: @Prune You're right, I thought the task was to find the teams.

Comment: @user11067275 don't loop over students. Loop over an array of size 16 (0-15) which will have a count of how many times each decimal occurred. Now, for each student, you just loop over this array and check what all bits are required and if that number has the bit set. If yes, add it's count to the final answer

Comment: @vivek_23 Yeah! It's perfect. Reduced it straight to `O(n)`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry; I just read the comments that came in while I was writing my answer.  It appears that @vivek_23 and I had the same approach.

Comment: @user11067275 Glad to help :)

Comment: @Prune Never mind. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce the complexity on number of students by spending memory for the combinations of subjects.

Build a list of 2^`s` elements, where `s` is the quantity of subjects.  Index the list by the combinations of subjects, interpreted as a binary number.  For instance, `S2` has a value of 13, and is missing a value of 2.

First tally the "needs" that each student can fill.  For each combination of `1` bits in the student's known subjects, increment that index of the tally list.

```
for student in student_list:

    score =   # student's covered subjects as an int

    tally = [0]*16
    for idx in range(16):
        if idx & score == idx:
            tally[idx] += 1
```

You now have a list of how many students can cover each combination of needed subjects.  This is **O(n * 2^s)**

For each student, find the *needed* score, the 1's complement of the student score.  It is now a simple matter to add all of the tallies for the needed scores.

```
team_ct = 0

for student in student_list:

    needed =   # student's needed subjects as an int; this is 15-score (above)
    team_ct += tally[needed]
```

Now, every pairing has been counted twice, so divide `team_ct` by 2.
Yes, this last bit of code can be dropped into a one-liner:

```
team_ct = sum([tally[15-score] for score in foo]) / 2
```

Where `foo` is a construct of all student scores.  This part is **O(n)**.

Comment: I want to mention that, while it would add extra complexity and save little time for the case of `4` subjects, the time complexity can be brought down to `O(n*2^(s/2))`, by using the same trick as the subset sum problem.

Comment: Instead of iterating over the entire powerset of subjects in stage 1, iterate over the powerset of half of the subjects (`2^(s/2)`), the incrementing a preallocated counter bin `tally[half1_idx][half2_score] += 1`. Then in stage 2, repeat the other half of the process- index into `tally` then iterate over the second half powerset, keeping a running sum.

Comment: Good points.  If 2^s grows larger than we want to iterate over, this will knock the running time back to something tractable.  In the given problem description, practical numbers will keep the running time well within bounds, but your update would be good for a different paradigm with the same combinatorics.